# Add filters to heatmap on R Shiny?

Tags: r, visualization, shiny-reactivity

I'm a beginner at this. So I would like to have a heatmap on R Shiny, with interactive filters.

An example of my raw data: (the table has 11 columns total)
part 1
[image]

part2
[image]

Here is an example of my heatmap, I would like to show the median resale price (denoted by the numbers under each apartment type (1/2/3 RM etc) by each town. The intensity of the heatmap is based on the resale price.

*below is the heatmap intended visualisation, but do imagine that each cell has a colour intensity.
[image]

However, under Shiny App, I would like to have interactive filters that changes what is shown on the heatmap based on certain variable such as the resale price, the remaining lease. Yet these variables are not included in the matrix.

Hence my question is, how can I get the filters to interact with the heatmap if the variables are not inside the matrix used? How can I have the variables added to the matrix, yet it will not be 'shown' on the heatmap?

On my shiny app, here is my code and how it looks like right now:
[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)
library(quantmod)
library(ggpubr)
library(plotly)

#import data
fp <- read.csv("../data/resale-flat-prices/resale-flat-prices-based-on-registration-date-from-jan-2017-onwards.csv")

#data cleaning
HDB_grouped <- group_by(fp, `town`,`flat_type`,`flat_model`)

HDB_summarised <- summarise(HDB_grouped,
                            `Total Unit Sold` = n(),
                            `Median Unit Price ($ psm)` = median(`resale_price`, na.rm = TRUE),
                            `Lease Yr Remaining` = median(2019 - `lease_commence_date`))
#print(HDB_summarised)
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Past HDB Resale Transaction Prices"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("priceInput", "Price", min = 0, max = 10000000,
                        value = c(0,0), pre = "$"),
            sliderInput("leaseInput", "Lease Year", min = 0, max = 99,
                        value = c(0,0), pre = "Years"),
            checkboxGroupInput("flattypeInput", "Flat type",
                                            choices = c("2 Room", "3 Room", "4 Room", "5 Room", "Executive")),
            checkboxGroupInput("flatmodelInput", "Flat Model",
                               choices = c("Improved", "New", "Executive", "DBSS"))
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("heat")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$heat <-renderPlot({
        lease_filter_data <- HDB_summarised[HDB_summarised$`Lease Yr Remaining` %in% input$leaseInput ]
        lease_filter_data
        heatmaply(lease_filter_data)
    })

    output$heatMap <- renderPlot({
        filtered <-
            HDB_summarised %>%
            filter(Price >= input$priceInput[1],
                   Price <= input$priceInput[2],
                   Flattype == input$flattypeInput,
                   FlatModel == input$flatmodelInput
            )
        fp_heatmap <- heatmaply(HDB_summarised,scale="column")    
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

A brief description of what I'm trying to do:

1. Import the raw data and clean it into **HDB_summarised**
2. Create interactive filters on variables like lease year, price range etc and then filter my **HDB_summarised** table based on the user input
3. Get the HDB_summarised table, and plot it into a heatmap showing only the median prices based on Town and Flat Type.

I can't seem to get Steps #2 and #3 working.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: can you provide some examples of the data? Otherwise I can only suggest joining the other variables to this current data frame. Then you create a reactive dataframe for plotting based on the subsetting

Comment: @StupidWolf Hello, thanks so much for your reply! I've added in more details, if you could take a look at the question again, it'll be much appreciated. Thanks again! :)